# npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, open

Tags: angular-cli, angular6

**Agenda:** Create New angular project using cli

**Configuration :**
OS: Windows10 64bit
npm -v: 6.4.1
node -v: 9.11.1 
angular cli: latest

**Observed behavior on following command:**

```
c:\AngularDemo>ng new guessthenumber --inlineTemplate
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE guessthenumber/angular.json (3933 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/package.json (1321 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/README.md (1031 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/tsconfig.json (408 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/tslint.json (2837 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/.gitignore (503 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/index.html (301 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/polyfills.ts (3234 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/browserslist (388 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/karma.conf.js (964 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/tsconfig.app.json (166 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/tsconfig.spec.json (256 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (245 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1119 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/app/app.component.ts (1429 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (310 bytes)
CREATE guessthenumber/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\AngularDemo\guessthenumber\node_modules\.staging\@angular\core-483ac45b\esm2015\src\render3\instructions.js'
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\params\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-31T11_07_38_873Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

**Expected behavior:** It should have created project without any error

**What i have tried:**

npm cache clean --force --> Did not worked

disabled antivirus --> Did not worked

Ran cmd using administrator -->did not worked

Comment: I am also facing same issue . can someone help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm comming quite late here but I faced same problem and here is list of things which helped me out:

- Close IDE
- Make sure you're not running ng-server in separate console.
- Right click on file which is having problemn and uncheck 'Read Only' flag

Answer (score -2):

please try to create angular project using IDE like Visual studio.

i faced same issue When I use commend prompt to create the project .then I tried the same with visual studio I can able create without any issue .

Comment: I tried with visual code as well gives me same error.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio version 1.28.2 . which version you are using ?
------------
Version: 1.28.2 (user setup)
Commit: 7f3ce96ff4729c91352ae6def877e59c561f4850
Date: 2018-10-17T00:23:51.859Z
Electron: 2.0.9
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
Architecture: x64

Comment: Version: 1.28.2 (system setup)
Commit: 7f3ce96ff4729c91352ae6def877e59c561f4850
Date: 2018-10-17T00:23:51.859Z
Electron: 2.0.9
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
Architecture: x64